# Walk through for installing Flashcache. Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, flashcache

I have a new Samsung laptop (NP700Z5C), it has a 1Tb hard drive, with 8Gb SSD which under windows 8 was used for increasing performance, particularly boot up time. I understand that flashcache is an open source package that will allow me to do the same, but I'm finding it difficult to figure out how. I found this page (http://www.gerrit-tamboer.net/) which was very informative but I failed at the final mount (step 5).

Instead I downloaded flashcache and flashcache-utils from the software center. But there doesn't appear to be any instructions for the lay person about how to set it up.

Please could someone who has been successful provide some guidance, and if possible some step by step instructions?

[More details on my failed attempt using the above link...]
Following the link above, I try to unmount /home, and am told that /home is not mounted. I believe /home is on /dev/sda1 so I unmount it instead. Then I do:

```
sudo flashcache_create -p thru cachedev /dev/sdb /dev//disk/by-uuid/[uuid address for/dev/sda1]
```

And I have no warnings! So I mount the new flashcache device:

```
sudo mount /dev/mapper/cachedev /home
```

And that works too. But now I can't cd to /home:

```
cd
bash: cd: /home/eddy: No such file or directory
```

Now mount /home won't work, and nor will mount /dev/sda1. So I restart and none of my changes appear to have worked (dmsetup gives me ubuntu--vg-swap and ubuntu--vg-root only).

I'd be very grateful for any guidance at all. Thanks.

Comment: +1, please let us know if you find something

Comment: @GClaramunt, I will, meanwhile I have other issues. Since you have the same laptop as me please could take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/317107/samsung-laptop-monitor-black-screen? If you could go in to bios and find the key presses that would re-enable UEFI and Fast Boot I would be incredibly grateful. Thanks.