# How to restore Windows on a Samsung laptop with broken display?

Tags: uefi, samsung, bios

I have a broken monitor on my Samsung 7 chronos (NP700Z5C-S02UB), I can get it to show certain things in my external monitor, but only once Ubuntu starts to load. I really need to return the laptop to bestbuy so that they can repair it, but to do that I first need to return it to the windows 8 installation it came with. But I can't do that without first accessing the bios, and I can't access the bios because I never see the samsung startup screen from which I can press F2.

My laptop is one of those affected by the whole Samsung-bricks-in-linux thing, but I have only been booting it in bios mode.

I only just had it returned from BestBuy's Geek Squad (my god, I believe they are trained to treat customers poorly!), because the laptop initially came with the webcam not connected. It came back yesterday with details of an additional repair they'd found necessary - "Replaced the defective LCD panel". I'd never had problems with the LCD panel before I sent it away.

The monitor worked yesterday. This is a list of everything I have done since I had the laptop returned to me. I created a back up disk image of windows 8, I turned off UEFI and Fast Boot, I stuck in the Ubuntu 13.04 DVD, installed the system, and refreshed my files from my backup. I watched a TV episode through an external monitor. I unplugged the external monitor and messed around online for a while. Then I closed the laptop. When I reopened it 5 minutes later the screen was completely black, no pushings of buttons had any effect.

I held down the power cable for 4 seconds to shut down, and turned on again. I get the noise of the dvd drive starting up. I hear the harddrive powering up. The keyboard backlight comes on, along with the hard disk light and the power light. Nothing more.

I plug in the AC adapter... ...same result.

I plug in an external monitor...  ...success! The external monitor shows my desktop, and everything appears to work.

So, the screen is kaput! Though, the computer seems fine. But I can't change the bios settings because I never see the initial startup screen. Is there a way to get at the bios settings through an external? Or does anyone know the exact keys I'd have to press to change the settings back on this computer without observing the screen? (Pressing F2 immediately after booting up appears to work, I press F10 to "save changes and exit" then press return, and the computer boots.)

I need to return the laptop, it's been nothing but trouble to me, I'd hope they'd give me a refund but I expect they'll insist on taking 2 weeks to fix it), but whatever I do I first need to return it to Windows 8.

EDIT Following a suggestion from my house mate, it's not because the laptop thinks that the lid is open. `cat /proc/acpi/button/lid/LID0/state` returns `state: open`.

Comment: what settings do you want to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During boot, F2 will get you into the BIOS config.
Once you're the there, F9 will load the default configuration, you have to press ENTER for the yes/no confirmation dialog. The F10 will save and exit the changes. Again, you'll have to press ENTER for a yes/no confirmation dialog.
That should boot windows.

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I needed.